# Updating row data in DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to update the quantity and price whenever I click the button again but it is not working. Is there something wrong in my code? I tried everything. I am creating a simple Point of sales system where the user can just click buttons to add the menu and automate the calculation. I added incrementation for conditioning.

Have you any idea?

```
package sampletable;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SampleTable extends JFrame
{

    Container con;
    JPanel pane1,pane2;
    JButton btn1;

    JTable JT;
    String[] columns = {"Menu","Price","Quantity"};
    String[][] data = new String[0][0];
    Object [] row1 = new Object[3];
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    int price1=0;
    int price1Mul;
    int Clicks1=0;
    public SampleTable()
    {
        con = getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        pane1 = new JPanel();
        btn1 = new JButton("Food 1");
        btn1.addActionListener(new btnAction1());
        pane1.add(btn1);
        con.add(pane1);

        model.setDataVector(data, columns);
        JT = new JTable();
        JT.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        JT.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JT.setModel(model);

        JScrollPane JPS = new JScrollPane(JT);
        con.add(JPS);
        pane2 = new JPanel();
        con.add(pane2);    
    }
    /*In here I want to change the value thats why I use incrementation so 
    that the next click it would increment and satisfy the other if.*/

    public class btnAction1 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
            price1 = 20;
            price1Mul++;
            if (Clicks1 == 0)
            {
            row1[0] ="Food1";
            row1[1] =price1;
            row1[2] =price1Mul;
            model.addRow(row1);
            int x =  price1 * price1Mul;
            price1 = x;
            Clicks1++;
            }

            else if (Clicks1 == 1)
            {
                int addPrice = price1 * price1Mul;
                row1[0] ="Food1";
                row1[1] =addPrice;
                row1[2] =price1Mul;
            }
            }
    }
//Main Class
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 SampleTable ST = new SampleTable();
 ST.setTitle("Sample JTable");
 ST.setSize(500,500);
 ST.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 ST.setVisible(true);
 ST.setResizable(false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `model.addRow(row1)` outside of `if / else` block to add that row to your model whether or not the button was clicked. If you want to update last added row, you can simply remove it by `removeRow(int row)` and insert updated row as was mentioned before.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        price1 = 20;
        price1Mul++;
        if (Clicks1 == 0) {
            row1[0] = "Food1";
            row1[1] = price1;
            row1[2] = price1Mul;
            int x = price1 * price1Mul;
            price1 = x;
            Clicks1++;
        } else if (Clicks1 == 1) {
            int lasRowAdded = model.getRowCount() - 1;
            model.removeRow(lastRowAdded);
            int addPrice = price1 * price1Mul;
            row1[0] = "Food1";
            row1[1] = addPrice;
            row1[2] = price1Mul;
        }
        model.addRow(row1);
    }
```

Comment: But the table would be Food 1 20 1 Food 1 40 2 Food 1 60 3 The problem is I want to update in a single row only :(

Comment: Oh thank you sir! Kind sir !! Figure it already!! sorry for many question you are one kind programmer! :D Thank you once again :)) lastRowAdded should be 0 lol